# Why can't shared folders from Windows 8 be accessed by Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-shares

I have a Windows 8.1 installation, in which I'm logged in using my Microsoft account, and I'm trying to share a folder with my workgroup. I open the folder properties, go to advanced sharing, enable the "share this folder" checkbox, and set permissions so that everyone can read.

Then I go to my Windows 7 PC, which is on the same workgroup. Under network, I can see the Windows 8 PC, but when I try to expand it to see the shared folders, I get a `Windows cannot access \\WIN8` error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked your firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not stated if any network resources are available to Windows 8, but my guess it this issues has something to do with the network setup (Private vs Public). [Here](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-cannot-access-shared-folder-how-to-fix-it-in-windows-8/) is an article which may help you resolve this issue.

Highlights from the article...

> If you need access to some files on a remote computer, you only have
>   to enable file sharing. This isn’t as easy as it should be.

[image]

> If you play a little with these settings, you will notice that Windows
>   8 will “lie” to you sometimes when you establish a networking
>   connection. The “Yes, turn on sharing and connect to devices” is only
>   true if “Turn on file and printer sharing” is enabled in the Private
>   network settings and “No, don’t turn on sharing or connect to devices”
>   is only correct if “Turn off file and printer sharing” is enabled in
>   the Guest or Public network settings.

If the network is set to `Public` and sharing isn't turned on, resources may not be available to network PCs. You will need to change the network to `Private`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to trouble shoot through windows facility, see the below steps:
1. Right Click the Network icon
2. Select "Network and Sharing Center
3. You will get a window > Under > Change your network settings > Click on "Troubleshoot problems"
4. See Network > Click on "Network Adapter" > You will navigate to a popup window > click on next > select "All network adapters" or select specific adapter based on your requirement. > Click on "Next" > Close - here you can view the details of fixes also.

This worked for me perfectly, before this I done so many things unnecessarily and above solution worked for me.
My Prob was:
Able to ping and connect via RDP, but not able to access any of the shared folder in my LAN.